# 2D array of objects in Python

Tags: python, object, multidimensional-array

I'm converting some java code to python code and I ended up getting stumped on how to convert a 2D array of objects in Java to python.

Java code:

```
private Node nodes[][] = new Node[rows][columns];
```

How would I do this in python?

Comment: Basically, a list of lists. But it's *very* likely that there's no reason to start with initializing the list. See if a list comprehension works in your case, else write it as a loop with `nodes.append([])` and `nodes.extend` or `nodes.append` in another loop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that's what you want

```
nodes = [[Node() for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
```

But it is not always a good practice to initialize lists. For matrices it may make sense.

If you're wondering: Documentation about [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Demo code:

```
>>> class Node:
      def __repr__(self):
        return "Node: %s" % id(self)
>>> cols = 3
>>> rows = 4
>>> nodes = [[Node() for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(nodes)
[[Node: 41596976, Node: 41597048, Node: 41596904],
 [Node: 41597120, Node: 41597192, Node: 41597336],
 [Node: 41597552, Node: 41597624, Node: 41597696],
 [Node: 41597768, Node: 41597840, Node: 41597912]]
```

Comment: curious if you forgot a [ ] in there?

Comment: It looks funny; I would have assumed it would have been something like: nodes = [[Node() for j in range(cols)], [for i in range(rows)]]

Comment: @nobody what you wrote doesn't even work. I used nested `list comprehensions`

Comment: Couldn't/shouldn't you use `_` in place of the names `j` and `i`, given that you're only including anything there for synthetic reasons and you don't actually want the values stored anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Python doesnt really do 2d arrays. Here is a better explenation

[Its does lists instead](http://www.stev.org/post/2012/02/22/Python-2d-Arrays-dont-work.aspx)