# Represent Maze in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, maze

How could I represent the following maze in Python?

I would like to make a program that navigates it so that it goes from **Start** to **End**, while also going to every **Gate** before it reaches **End**.

I am not very familiar with data structures, so all help is appreciated!

[image: Maze]

Comment: What exactly will be the expected output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2D array of objects in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480441/2d-array-of-objects-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a [2d array of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480441/2d-array-of-objects-in-python). Some would suggest using [Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55660665/store-object-in-2-dimensional-array-in-python). A node object could have a type property (normal,start,end,gate) and some way to represent exits (North,South,East,West). For discovering all gates you would need to ensure all nodes were checked. Maybe this [strategy](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/solve-a-maze-with-python-e9f0580979a1) would help.

Answer (score 0):

This could be represented using arrays in python. For example if each node is a list with a state then a north east south west values (0,0) might look like this.

`['blank', 0, 1, 1, 0]`

Where the `0`s have no connection, `1`s are a connection, and `'blank'` is if it is a gate or what not. Then the first row

`[['blank', 0, 1, 1, 0],[],[],[]]`

Then all the rows

```
maze = [[[],[],[],[]],
        [[],[],[],[]],
        [[],[],[],[]],
        [[],[],[],[]]]
```

It would then be possible to read each list and know where you are and what is around you. So in this case if you wanted to print the information about the start

`print(maze(3,1))`
would output a list
`['start',0,1,0,1]`